# Send application/pdf content with http call

Tags: java, http, io

How can I upload a pdf with a http call to a server.

I am currently loading the pdf content to a variable and trying to send it with http:

```
byte[] pdfContent;

String output = "";

try {
    pdfContent = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:...//test.pdf"));
    url = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
    conn.setConnectTimeout(5000);
    conn.setReadTimeout(5000);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(pdfContent.toString());
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();
```

The error I am getting is:

```
 Wrong content! The content of file 'test.pdf' does not match its presumed content type ('application/pdf').
```

What is the right way to send a pdf for upload?
Is loading the binary content to a variable and writing it to the connection incorrect?

Comment: A PDF is not a string, and given `pdfContent` is a byte array, `pdfContent.toString()` will produce something like `[B@12345`, and finally, using a `DataOutputStream` is probably the wrong abstraction. Get a file input stream (`Files.newInputStream`) and call `transferTo(conn.getOutputStream)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried wr.write(pdfContent); ?
The write() function takes a byteArray as argument, so if the problem is caused by the conversion to String it might by solved that way

Comment: Well yes, such a stupid mistake. Thanks for pointing out